# Horton Sandbox - Ambari on AWS EC2 not loading (public IP)

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, networking, amazon-ec2, hortonworks-sandbox

I have the Horton HDP sandbox(Docker) installed and running in EC2 AWS. As the EC2 does not have a browser, I am not able to login to the ambari UI.

I have added the docker IP to the hosts file in EC2.

How can I access the Ambari UI from my local machine? The EC2 has a public IP,  when I try accessing the public IP in the browser
http://public-ip:1080... it does not return anything. The ambari service is running in EC2.

I believe this would work without any issues if I try it on a browser within EC2, but EC2 ubuntu does not have a browser.

Comment: Update your question with 1) VPC firewalls 2) Docker configuration

Answer (score 0):

The port 1080 was blocked in the security rule. I allowed all inbound traffic for now.